# Binary search tree from pre-order traversal and information about left and right nodes

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Need to validate if the given preorder traversal is a BST or not? The input that is file that contains a preorder traversal of a binary tree and also if the node has left, right, both or no children. For example

```
-2 3
-4 3
-5 0
-3 0
 2 3
 0 3
-1 0
 1 0
 5 1
 4 0
```

means that "-2" node has both left and right children. "-5" has no children. Basically

```
0 -> no children
1 -> right child
2 -> left child
3 -> both Children
```

this is the node structure which cannot be modified

```
    typedef struct _Tnode {
       int key;
       int height;
       struct _Tnode *left;
       struct _Tnode *right;
    } Tno
```

PS: In this example it is not a BST. The tree which I could construct out of this looks like this

```
                            -2 
                          /    \
                        /        \
                      -4          2
                      / \        /  \
                    -5   -3     0    5
                               / \    \
                             -1   1    4
```

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly, please [edit] your question to improve it, by example actually asking a question... What is the problem you have? Do you have an [mre] of your own attempt? What problems do you have with it?

Comment: I have spent decent amount of time researching this question and did not find any solution. Update the question as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to parse the input and check whether each value is within the acceptable range. It is not really needed to actually *build* the tree using the `Tno` type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int isBST(min, max) {
    int value, flags;
    scanf("%d %d", &value, &flags);
    if (value < min || value > max) return 0;
    if ((flags > 1) && !isBST(min, value)) return 0;
    if ((flags % 2 > 0) && !isBST(value, max)) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int result = isBST(INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    if (result) printf("This BST is fine\n");
    else        printf("Not a valid BST\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### Building the tree

If you need to build the tree, and only then verify whether it is a BST, then here is how you could do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct _Tnode {
    int key;
    int height;
    struct _Tnode *left;
    struct _Tnode *right;
} Tno;

Tno* createNode(int key) {
    Tno* node = malloc(sizeof(Tno));
    node->key = key;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

Tno* discardTree(Tno* node) {
    if (node == NULL) return NULL;
    discardTree(node->left);
    discardTree(node->right);
    free(node);
    return NULL;
}

Tno* createTreeFromInput() {
    int value, flags;
    scanf("%d %d", &value, &flags);
    Tno* node = createNode(value);
    if (flags > 1) node->left = createTreeFromInput();
    if (flags % 2 > 0) node->right = createTreeFromInput();
    return node;
}

int isBST(Tno* node, int min) {
    if (node == NULL) return min;
    if (node->key < min) return INT_MAX; // Indication of error
    min = isBST(node->left, min);
    if (min > node->key) return INT_MAX;
    return isBST(node->right, node->key);
}

int main(void) {
    Tno* root = createTreeFromInput();
    int ok = isBST(root, INT_MIN) < INT_MAX;
    if (ok) printf("This BST is fine\n");
    else    printf("Not a valid BST\n");
    discardTree(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will surely try this solution, but the reason I want to build the tree is , later I also want to check for the balance of each node to determine if the tree is AVL?

Comment: OK, but that was not your question, right? If you have trouble proving whether the input tree is a balanced AVL tree, then that would be stuff for a new question.

Comment: Hmm... by lack of reaction I have added a section to my answer. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Any feedback to this addition?